# What is the behavior of os.path.join() with UNC path?

Tags: python

Can someone explain the rules of joining path, I am confusing with these results:

```
print(os.path.join('\\\\192.168.1.1\\A\\B', 'C\\D', '\\E')) #\\192.168.1.1\A\E, B,C,D are thrown away
print(os.path.join('\\\\192.168.1.1\\', 'C\\D', '\\E')) #\\192.168.1.1\\E, C, D are thrown away
print(os.path.join('\\\\192.168.1.1', 'C\\D', '\\E')) #\E, \\192.168.1.1 is thrown away
print(os.path.join('C:\\A\\B', 'C\\D', '\\E')) #C:\E, A, B, C, D are thrown away
```

Comment: Don't use path separators in the arguments to `os.path.join()`. The whole point of `os.path.join()` is that it does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

An absolute path (like `'\\E'`) *replaces* the current path, rather than being appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

From [[Python.Docs]: os.path.join(path, *paths)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) (**emphasis** is mine):

> ...
> If a component is an absolute path, **all previous components are thrown away** and joining continues from the absolute path component.

> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., `r'\foo'`) is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` `(c:foo)`, not `c:\foo`.

So (in *os.path.join*), the last absolute path (and *UNC* paths **are** absolute) discards any other path preceding it.

Comment: does anybody have an idea on why this is done that way and in which situation it is useful or needed or necessary? I can only think of situations where it's absolutely inconvenient having to remove all leading / gefore calling join, and none where i feed multiple values but want some to be droppped because they start with a /.